# How to implement structures for difference equations?

Tags: filters, delay

I want to learn how to design structures that could model difference equations. I don't know how we call this things but i can show a picture:

[image]

For example i want to understand the procedure that using addition, multiplication and delay operators like the above i can describe equations like: $ y(k)=1/2(x(k)+x(k-1)) $

Does anyone knows any resources like books, tutorials , articles that explain how to design these structures?

Comment: This diagram, called a *signal flowgraph*, would be used in pretty much any introductory digital signal processing text. There are a few different major classes of common filter structures (the above looks like a [transposed direct form I](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Transposed_Direct_Forms.html) topology). What about the above diagram are you having trouble understanding? You seem to understand the functions of the three operators used there.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a "digital filter implementation"?

Comment: @endolith - A digital filter implementation would be one realization of a general system as described in the diagram.  it is unclear what the OP is asking for.  There are lots of books on discrete time signal processing that provide guidance on how to implement this kind of structure in software.  The implementation is very specific to the development tools in use, particularly the choice of language.  If the OP provides some indication of what environment is targeted for the implementation, I'm sure someone can provide references.